# C adding array a word

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char in_name[80];
    FILE *in_file;
    char word[50];
    char word2[50];
    char word3[50];
    char *strs[]= {"foo ABAA", "bar", "bletch","4"};
    strcpy(*strs[4],"wow");
    in_file = fopen("test2.txt", "r");

    if (in_file == NULL)
        printf("Can't open %s for reading.\n", in_file);
    else
    {
        while (fscanf(in_file, "%s %s %s ", word,word2,word3) != EOF)
        {

            printf("%s ", word);
            printf("%s ", word2);
            printf("%s\n", word3);
        }
        fclose(in_file);
    }
    printf("%s",strs[3]);
    int result = atoi(strs[3] );
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Im new in C.Im trying to add the "woo" string to the strs array.But it gives an error.Im open to any help.My main point is reading line by line a txt file and adding every word to a array like {"what", "a", "nice","day"}

Comment: "But it gives an error." Details, please.

Comment: @FredLarson incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy'

Comment: Sounds like you need `#include <string.h>`, then.

Comment: @FredLarson now it says this 
passing argument 1 of makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting sucked into fixing your compile errors one at a time.

Comment: @FredLarson, indeed. Seems he is more interested in fixing the compile errors than in fixing the code.

Comment: Arrays in C are indexed `[0 -> n-1]`. `char *strs[]= {"foo ABAA", "bar", "bletch","4"};` creates an *array of pointers* to **string-literals** that cannot be modified. (you can use a *compound literal* to initialize to a pointer to array of `char[]` in C99+)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps you must take:

To read a potentially unlimited number of words from your file, you must have an array `strs` that can hold enough words. Let's say 50:

```
char *strs[50]= 0;
```

But this is an array of *pointers* to strings; the pointers still point nowhere. So you must have memory to store the strings read. We will allocate the memory after each word read.

You open the file and start reading. For each word read, you allocate the memory and store it in the `strs` array. Then you copy the word to the memory you have just allocated:

```
    int i= 0;
    while (fscanf(in_file, "%s %s %s ", word,word2,word3) != EOF)
    {
        strs[i]= malloc(strlen(word )+1; strcpy(strs[i],word ); i++;
        strs[i]= malloc(strlen(word2)+1; strcpy(strs[i],word2); i++;
        strs[i]= malloc(strlen(word3)+1; strcpy(strs[i],word3); i++;
    }
    fclose(in_file);
```

Thats's all...

---

what you did wrong and needs noticing:

```
char *strs[]= {"foo ABAA", "bar", "bletch","4"};
```

Ths is an array that you initialize with the values between `{` and `}`. You do not specify the size and the size is taken by counting the number of initializers between the `{` and `}`.

You initialize the array with *literal strings*. These are constants and cannot be modified. So when you do:

```
strcpy(*strs[4],"wow");
```

you do **4** things wrong: 1) entry 4 is beyond your array; 2) you dereference a pointer (`strs[4]` is already a pointer, so no `*` needed), and even if we forget this last error, you try 3) to overwrite a read-only string, and that is not allowed.  And finally, 4) the string you try to copy is much longer than the string that was there, so even if the string was not read-only, you make an error.

```
while (fscanf(in_file, "%s %s %s ", word,word2,word3) != EOF)
```

This use of `scanf` is not really wrong but it is always better to compare the result with the number of items you want to read. 3 here. Also, we still must guard against reading too many words:

```
while (i<47 && fscanf(in_file, "%s %s %s ", word,word2,word3)==3)
```

Comment: `strcpy(strs[4],"wow");` ... `strs[4]` is beyond the end of the array in OP's code (`strs[3]` is the final pointer `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yeah, that too. Updated my answer.